# SQL: Find the status change date for a user in a given time period

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables: Table A has today's data and Table B has the historical snapshot of the data captured on a daily basis.

```
**Table A**
User  Status  Date (which is current_date) 
A1    A       12/23/2019
B1    B       12/23/2019

**Table B**
User  Status  Date
A1    B       12/20/2019
A1    A       12/21/2019
A1    B       12/22/2019
A1    A       12/23/2019
B1    A       12/20/2019
B1    B       12/21/2019
B1    A       12/22/2019
B1    B       12/23/2019
```

What I am looking for are: in 2019

1. For users who are currently on status B, what are the dates when the status was changed to B from A (as users can switch between status multiple times so I want all dates when that happened, if the change happened in 2019)
2. For users who are currently on status B, what is the most recent date the status was changed to B from A (a subset of users from list above)
3. For users who are currently on status A and was on status B earlier this year, what is the date when it was changed to B (if the user was A before B) and when it was changed to A

Thanks!

Comment: What result set do you want?  It is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want `lag()` and `last_value()`.  Table `A` does not seem necessary.

The basic logic to get what you want is:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             last_value(status) over (partition by user order by date) as last_status,
             lag(status) over (partition by user order by date) as prev_status
      from b
     ) b
where date >= '2019-01-01' and
      date < '2020-01-01' and
      ((last_status = 'B' and status = 'B' and prev_status = 'A') or
       (last_status = 'B' and status = 'B' and prev_status = 'A') or
       (last_status = 'A' and status = 'A' <> prev_status)
      )
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to confirm: using `(last_status = 'B' and status = 'A' and prev_status = 'B')` will give me all dates when the status was changed to B from A, not just the most recent one, correct? Also, looks like the last one would be `(last_status = 'A' and status <> prev_status)`. Besides, in Redshefit, I need to add `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` when using last_value()

Comment: @user12562215 . . . No, it is the other way around.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: got it. So to answer the question #1 and #2 I have, I just need to check `(last_status = 'B' and status = 'B' and prev_status = 'A')`?

Comment: @user12562215 . . . That is the basic filtering.  You seem to want more filtering for the second question. If these are separate questions, then your Stack Overflow question is too broad.

Comment: I see. Yeah so for the 2nd question I think that's easier to complete. But for the 1st one looks like what you offer really works! Thanks again!